# Can't start make command from python subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, makefile, subprocess

I tried to build project by make in python on macOS Mojave, but I get this output:

> If there are problems, cd to the src directory and run make there
>   cd src && /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make first
>   rm -f auto/config.status auto/config.cache config.log auto/config.log
>   rm -f auto/config.h auto/link.log auto/link.sed auto/config.mk
>   touch auto/config.h
>   cp config.mk.dist auto/config.
>   Process finished with exit code 0

But if I try start make from terminal all works fine.
Here my python code:

```
make_command = "make"
make_proc = subprocess.Popen(make_command, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, cwd=args[1])
```

args[1] – path to folder with project, its correct ("/Users/kirill/.vim_updater")

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have any error/traceback? Why do you need to have `shell=True` flag?

Comment: @milanbalazs There are no errors, the process ends correctly. The only stdout is a message about a problem with make. Yep, `shell=True` isn't needed. But this improvement don't fix problem with make. I have same output from make

Comment: Could you update your question with your output? Perhaps it makes easier to give a solution.

Comment: @milanbalazs I updated question, but it's all my output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a newbie and still don't have enough reputatio to comment.

So please feel free to try this out and tell me and so that I can delete this 'answer'

Use subprocess.call() instead of subprocess.Popen()
you also want to check the return code.

I think you want to wait for the result.

For testing you might also try to use the absolute path of the make command.

Comment: Thx, final solution:
`make_proc = subprocess.call([make_command], cwd=args[1])`

Comment: should be `returncode = subprocess.call([make_command], cwd=args[1])`

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your question `Process finished with exit code 0`. It means your `make` command was success. You can try the following improved code part.

**Code:**

```
import subprocess
import sys

make_command = ["make"]
make_proc = subprocess.Popen(make_command, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, cwd=sys.argv[1])
stdout, stderr = make_proc.communicate()
print("stdout: {}".format(stdout))
print("stderr: {}".format(stderr))
print("Return code: {}".format(make_proc.returncode))
```

**Output:** (If there is no `Makefile` in the specific folder. You can see the return code is not zero because of missing `Makefile` (error))

```
>>> python3 test.py .
stdout: b'make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.\n'
stderr: None
Return code: 2
```

And if I create a `Makefile` in my `.` (root) folder with the following content.

**Makefile:**

```
FOO = Hello World

all:
    @echo $(FOO)
    @echo $(value FOO)
```

**Output:** (The `Makefile` exists in the specific folder and the content of it is correct so the `make` was success and the return code is zero (**You have the same situation based on your question**).)

```
>>> python3 test.py .
stdout: b'Hello World\nHello World\n'
stderr: None
Return code: 0
```

Comment: Implementation through `subprocess.Popen` did not work, but I did it using `subprocess.Popen.call`. The problem was that I passed the argument to the wrong position. Thx for you answer

Comment: `subprocess.Popen` does not have `call` attribute so you are not able to use `subprocess.Popen.call`. I think you mean `subprocess.call()`. On the other hand, if you had problem with positions of arguments then, the `.Popen` should also work. :)